# Pyspark: can I read file from google cloud from databricks?

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am working on Databricks and I would like to know if I can read `csv` file from google cloud.

I was trying to read this guideline: https://docs.databricks.com/data/data.html

I can read the data locally in Python in this way

```
path = 'myJson.json'
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = path
client = storage.Client()
name = 'https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/myBucket/'
bucket_id = 'myBucket'
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_id)

df = pd.read_csv('gs://myBucket/feed/us/2020/03/19/18/data0000000001.csv.gz, compression='gzip')
```

Comment: Please have a look on the below link that has suggested to use IR to import the data from GCP to Azure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-google-cloud-storage

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, connectivity to Google Cloud is not supported as a source in Azure Databricks.

Supported Data Sources in Azure Databricks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/

As per my research, I have found a third-party tool named "Panoply" which you can [Start analyzing your Google Cloud Storage data with Databricks](https://panoply.io/integrations/databricks/google-cloud-storage/).

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To read the file directly from Google cloud storage, bucket can be mounted to DBFS and then it can used seamlessly to fetch data from GCS bucket. All the steps can be found on the databricks official documentation: https://docs.gcp.databricks.com/data/data-sources/google/gcs.html

Comment: this documentation is for GCP Databricks that is different from Azure Databricks that author uses